# Laravel 8 Jetstream: adding new field to the registration process

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I started building a web application using Laravel 8. I have noticed that quite a lot of things have changed in Laravel 8 including authentication. Now, I am trying to use Jetstream for auth.

I have run the following command to integrate it into the application.

```
composer require laravel/jetstream
php artisan jetstream:install inertia
npm install && npm run dev
```

When I go to the `/register` route, I can see the registration form with name, email, password and password confirmation fields. What I would like to do is that I would like to add another field called, "company" and I would like to apply custom validation rules to it.

I found on the Jetstream documentation that I could customise the authentication process in the boot method of the JetstreamServiceProvider class as follow.

```
Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
            
        });
```

But it does not apply to register. How can I customise the registration process adding new fields and applying custom validation rules?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Firstly, you should add the `company` field to the user table using the migration found in `database\migrations\2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php`.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('company');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->foreignId('current_team_id')->nullable();
            $table->text('profile_photo_path')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Then run this command `php artisan migrate:fresh` to migrate your new users table.

Then add the field to the fillable array inside the `User` model found in `\app\Models\User.php` like so:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'company',
    'email',
    'password',
];
```

And now you can find the registration view under `resources\views\auth\register.blade.php` then you can duplicate an input block to use it for the `'company'` field.

Then you can do the validation in this class: `app\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser.php`

```
public function create(array $input)
    {
        Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'company' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
        ])->validate();

        return User::create([
            'name' => $input['name'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'company' => $input['company'],
            'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

Then, you are ready.

Comment: Cheers Ali Ali. This is what I am looking for.

Comment: The command `php artisan migrate:fresh` will give you a warning on the production environment. This is because the data from your database tables will be lost after running this command.

Comment: @ArifI. Yes, my answer applies to the newly created projects only, as the question above mentioned. On production env, we should update the existing table without dropping it.

Comment: ZOMG, almost crazy looking for the Fortify files... there are just in the new folder Actions. Thanks!

Comment: For adding styles for custom inputs like select you can add: ```border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm  w-full```

Answer (score 4):

@Ali Ali's answer is correct however if for those of you using Inertia there is one additional step. You'll need to open `resources/js/Pages/Auth/Register.vue` and add the desired field to the form. Additionally, scroll down to the bottom of the file and add the field name to the `this.$inertia.form` input parameter object literal. For instance if the desired additional field name is `company` you'll add it like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    form: this.$inertia.form({
      name: '',
      company: '', // <- New line here
      email: '',
      password: '',
      password_confirmation: '',
      terms: false,
    })
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, are these correct answers? If you install LiveWire then yes you could edit `resources/views/auth/register.blade.php` but with Inertia and Vue there is no such folder or file (at least in the current version). In fact there is only one file by default in the `resources/views`folder: app.blade.php. If I got it right by design strict Inertia use does not use blade files.
Am I correct?
If so then the questions is not answered. Where should you add new fields when using Inertia. And in my case, using Spatie/permissions, how do you create logic to reference role information?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).