# Change Laravel Fortify Auth Column Names

Tags: laravel, laravel-fortify

I tried following these steps to no avail
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64299968/7309037

I have a User Table with the column name "EmailAddress" but Laravel is looking for "email" and I get the following error when trying to login:

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'email'. (SQL: select top 1 * from [User] where [email] = test1@gmail.com)  A column was not found`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/fortify#customizing-user-authentication

Add the following code to your FortifyServiceProvider file in the boot method:

```
Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
        $user = User::where('EmailAddress', $request->email)->first();
 
        if ($user &&
            Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            return $user;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I dont have those in my FortifyServiceProvider :(

Comment: And if you add the entire code? I've updated my answer.